# How do I change the access rights in NT namespace from command line?

Tags: windows

I want to change the access rights to an object of the "section" type in NT namespace using command line. Can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

From Command Prompt and without any 3rd-party app? No. Absolutely not.

From Windows PowerShell? Oh, you can do anything from PowerShell, as you can access the full spectrum of Windows API from it. But doing so can be insurmountably difficult.

If you want details of how to do it, however, you must ask this question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). We don't address programming questions in this site.

Comment: But one can start any PowerShell script from command prompt, yes? And I do not exclude use of third-party tools.

Comment: @Anixx LOL! Good one. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nitpick

Comment: My point was that there are graphical tools for the task, but I want to automatize it.

Comment: The verb is "automate". Good luck. Let us know what happens.